# How I do make a colormap based off 12 arrays (12 months)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter, colormap

My goal is to create a color map that is based on month.
I have two data sets of monthly data (same length, etc).
However I want to plot a scatter plot of the two data sets, but the colormap to be colored based on the month. Hopefully this makes more sense as I walk through the example:

These are the two data sets I am plotting against each other as a scatter plot:

```
data1 = np.random.rand(360)

data2 = np.random.rand(360)
```

I then use this function (split_months) to turn data1 and data2 into a 2-dimensional array of size 12, 30. This is just like regrouping by month, where 12 represents all the months, and 30 is all the years of that particular month:

```
def split_months(monthly_data):
    month_split = []
    for month in range(12):
        month_split.append(monthly_data[month::12])
    month_split = np.array(month_split)
    return month_split


split_data1 = split_months(data1)

split_data2 = split_months(data2)

print(split_data1.shape, split_data2.shape)

(12, 30) (12, 30)
```

I then reshape the split month data into a 1D array by basically having the first month and all the years, preceded by the second month and all the years. So making a 1-dimensional array but reordering it by each month and thus number of years (as seen by example below):

```
split_months_reshape_data1= split_data1.reshape(12*30) ## reshaping so organized by month now (jan - dec for all years)

split_months_reshape_data2 = split_data2.reshape(12*30) 

print(split_data1[0])

print(split_months_reshape_data1[:30])

[0.70049451 0.24326443 0.29633189 0.35540148 0.68205274 0.15130453
 0.34046832 0.54975106 0.4502673  0.39086571 0.5610824  0.88443547
 0.85777702 0.39887896 0.82240821 0.31162978 0.23496537 0.68776803
 0.84677736 0.04060598 0.7735167  0.23317739 0.49447141 0.53932027
 0.62494628 0.19676697 0.41435389 0.22843223 0.22817976 0.09133836]

[0.70049451 0.24326443 0.29633189 0.35540148 0.68205274 0.15130453
 0.34046832 0.54975106 0.4502673  0.39086571 0.5610824  0.88443547
 0.85777702 0.39887896 0.82240821 0.31162978 0.23496537 0.68776803
 0.84677736 0.04060598 0.7735167  0.23317739 0.49447141 0.53932027
 0.62494628 0.19676697 0.41435389 0.22843223 0.22817976 0.09133836]

## data arrays are the same, split_months is showing all of the numbers for the first month, while split_months_reshape_data1 is showing the first 30 values which is the same as the `split_months[0]`
```

Now the question is, is there a way to use each of the 12 arrays in split_months, to create a colormap (January - December) but using those specific values in each array?
For example, for January, using the values from `split_months[0]` to make one color for the colormap. Then for February, use the values from `split_months[1]` to make another color for the colormap

This is the idea I was going for, but the colorbar is not correct:

```
plt.scatter(split_months_reshape_data1,split_months_reshape_data2, c = split_data1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please let me know if my question needs clarification, it is a bit specific, however the main goal is to obtain a colormap based on the reshaped data array (`split_data1` and `split_data2`).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to use 12 unique colors that are taken from a continuous colormap (e.g. Viridis rather than Set3), but instead of showing them with a standard legend containing 12 small rectangles, you would like to display them as a colorbar with 12 sections (with labels for the months instead of numbers, I assume)?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I tried creating a discrete colormap, but they only take hard boundaries (like specific values) rather than an array of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting colors from a colormap is quite simple, as shown in the [matplotlib colormap tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html). There are two types of [colormap objects](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colors_api.html) (LinearSegmentedColormap and ListedColormap) and they do not have exactly the same methods to select the colors. Here is how to select colors from the viridis colormap (ListedColormap), using the [pyplot interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html):

```py
# Select colormap with a certain number of colors
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 12)

# Generate list of colors in these 3 equivalent ways for a ListeColormap
colors = cmap.colors  # this method is not applicable to LinearSegmentedColormaps
colors = cmap(range(12))
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, 12))
```

Creating the colorbar is the trickier part. The dataset you are plotting consists of 3 variables:

1. month (categorical): plotted as hue
2. data1 (numerical): plotted as the x variable
3. data2 (numerical): plotted as the y variable

As you have seen in your example, the variable passed to `c` (i.e. `split_data1`, the x variable) is mapped to the colorbar created with `plt.colorbar()`. While it is possible to pass values corresponding to the months to `c` to create the colorbar (see alternative solution shown below after figure), I find the code easier to understand if instead the colors for the months are preselected and then passed to `color`. The colorbar can be then created separately from the plot, as shown in [the second example of the Customized Colorbars Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#extended-colorbar-with-continuous-colorscale).

Here is an example where the data reshaping part is simplified by using several numpy functions and where the scatter plot is created using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to loop through the sub-arrays and the related months and colors. The names of the months are generated with the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to save a bit of typing.

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np                   # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      # v 3.3.4

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)  # random number generator
data1 = rng.random(360)
data2 = rng.random(360)

# Reshape data
split_data1 = np.stack(np.split(data1, 30)).transpose()
split_data2 = np.stack(np.split(data2, 30)).transpose()

# Generate lists of months and colors
months = [dt.strptime(str(m), '%m').strftime('%B') for m in range(1, 13)]
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')  # no need to preselect number of colors in this case
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(months)))

# Draw scatter plot by looping over zipped sub-arrays, colors and months
for x, y, c, month in zip(split_data1, split_data2, colors, months):
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=c, label=month)

# Add colorbar
bounds = np.arange(len(months)+1)
norm = plt.matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
cbar = plt.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ticks=bounds+0.5)
cbar.set_ticklabels(months)

# Optional extra formatting
cbar.ax.tick_params(length=0, pad=7)
cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image: custom_colorbar]

For the sake of completeness, here is an alternative solution that uses the `c` argument in `plt.scatter` (instead of `color`) to generate the colorbar directly from the plot:

```
# Prepare data...

# months and cmap are the same as before
months = [dt.strptime(str(m), '%m').strftime('%B') for m in range(1, 13)]
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

# Create objects needed to map the months to colors and create a colorbar
bounds = np.arange(13)
norm = plt.matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# Draw scatter plot, notice how there is no need for colors
for x, y, month, bound in zip(split_data1, split_data2, months, bounds):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=np.repeat(bound, len(x)), norm=norm, cmap=cmap, label=month)
cbar = plt.colorbar()

# Format colorbar
cbar.set_ticklabels(months)
cbar.set_ticks(bounds+0.5)
cbar.ax.tick_params(length=0, pad=7)
cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
```